# Kibana has not available Connectors with OSS

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I was trying the latest version of ELK 8.12 and for my surprise I can't add any kind of connector for alerts without a GOLD license, with the version 7.x there was available at least the Webhook, but with the latest version they don't even enable the Webhook options.

Is there an alternative to use the the alerts and trigger a webhook?

[image]

### Solution!

Create a connector to send the alert into an specific index and monitor that index with Grafana or elastalert2

[image]

Comment: I don't think there was a webhook in 7.x available in the basic version. We never change a free feature to a paid one. Do you have a link to the 7.x doc?

Comment: Yeah, you could always set up the alert and do an action within the cluster (log, index) but any action going out of the cluster was always a paid or Cloud feature.

Comment: @dadoonet lol same as discussed on reddit it was the AWS version, It was easy then, but now...
I just didn'tn knew AWS had their own custom layer/plugins